# Problem with a simple graphic

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hey guys thanks in advance for reading me.

I made a figure to ilustrate $|z|$ .

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-fct} 
\begin{center}  
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\tkzInit[xmin=-.5, xmax=4, ymin=-.5, ymax=3] 
\tkzDrawXY[noticks,label={}] 
\tkzDefPoint(3,2){z}
\tkzDefPoint(3,0){x} 
\tkzDefPoint(0,2){y} 
\tkzDefPoint(1.5,1){a}
\tkzDrawPoint[fill=black,size=12](z)
\tkzDrawPoint[fill=black,size=12](x)
\tkzDrawPoint[fill=black,size=12](y)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](z) 
\tkzLabelPoints[below](x) 
\tkzLabelPoints[left](y)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](a) 
\draw (z) -- (0,0); 
\draw [dashed] (z) -- (x); 
\draw [dashed] (z) -- (y); 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

But in `\tkzDefPoint(1.5,1){a}` I would like replace for `$|z|$` but if I do it, I got a message error of runaway argument. Any suggestion please?

Comment: You can always use ordinary Ti*k*Z commands: `\path (a) node[above left]{$|z|$};`. Also please add `\begin{document}`, and remove `\usepackage{tikz}` and the second `\usepackage{tkz-fct}`.

Comment: you saved me again!

Comment: Schrödinger's cat is right !  A few clarifications  `a` is the référence of the node and `$|z|$` is the label as for `\node (a) at (0,0) {$|z|$};` There is a difference between `a` and `$|z|$`. You need to use `\tkzLabelPoint(a){{$|z|$}` or like  Schrödinger's cat  wrote `\path (a) node[above left]{$|z|$};.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that you can do this with pure `tkz-euclide` but there is always the possibility to use Ti*k*Z where it is efficient.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={inner sep=3pt,fill,circle}]
\tkzInit[xmin=-.5, xmax=4, ymin=-.5, ymax=3] 
\tkzDrawXY[noticks,label={}] 
\draw (0,0) coordinate (O)
 (3,2) coordinate[bullet,label=above right:$z$] (z)
 (z|-O) coordinate[bullet,label=below:$x$] (x)
 edge[dashed] (z)
 (z-|O) coordinate[bullet,label=left:$y$] (y)
 edge[dashed] (z)
 (O) -- node[sloped,above]{$|z|$} (z);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={inner sep=3pt,fill,circle}]
\tkzInit[xmin=-.5, xmax=4, ymin=-.5, ymax=3] 
\tkzDrawXY[noticks,label={}] 
\tkzDefPoints{3/0/x,0/2/y,3/2/z,1.5/1/a,0/0/o}
\tkzDefPoint(3,0){x} 
\tkzDrawPoints[fill=black,size=8](x,y,z)
\tkzLabelPoints[right=6pt](z) 
\tkzLabelPoints[below=6pt](x) 
\tkzLabelPoints[left=6pt](y)
\tkzDrawSegments[dashed](x,z y,z)
\tkzDrawSegments(o,z)
\tkzLabelSegment[above,sloped](o,z){$|z|$}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A trivial usage of PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0.4102020cm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\pspicture[arrowscale=2,arrowinset=0](-1,-1)(7,6)
    \pnode(0,0){O}
    \pstGeonode[dotscale=2,LabelSep=5mm,PosAngle={-90,45,180}](5,0){x}(5,4){z}(0,4){y}
    \pcline[nodesepA=-0.5,nodesepB=-2]{->}(O)(x)
    \pcline[nodesepA=-0.5,nodesepB=-2]{->}(O)(y)
    \pcline(O)(z)\naput[nrot=:U]{$|z|$}
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](x)(z)(y)
\endpspicture
\end{document}
```